# Use OverlapSphere to fill a list?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to fill a list with objects by using OverlapSphere.
Any Object with tag "enemy" goes in OverlapSphere radius put it in the list. This object goes out remove it from the list.

```
public GameObject[] listEnemy;

void Update()
{
 Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(gameObject.transform.position, 2);
    foreach (Collider hitCol in hitColliders)
    {
        if (hitCol.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {

            //// evey object with tag "enemy" put in the listEnemy.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered filtering the collision check to an "enemy" physics layer so you don't need do the tag check at all, and can just use the results of the query directly? Also, note that a List is a distinct type that you're not using here — everything you've defined in this code uses arrays, not lists.

Comment: Sorry. I what i meant is a LIST of objects. Array do the same thing here ? I think yes. I need to use tag because it's easy to read. Could you help me to solve this headache issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not the right tools for the job you're describing.

If you want to incrementally add & remove tagged objects as they enter & leave a spherical region, you more likely want to use an object with a SphereCollider set to IsTrigger, with a script something like this what's below, taking advantage of the inside/outside state tracking the physics engine can already do for us.

```
List<GameObject> enemiesInRange = new List<GameObject>();

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if(collider.CompareTag("enemy")) 
       enemiesInRange.Add(other.attachedRigidbody.gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    if(collider.CompareTag("enemy")) 
       enemiesInRange.Remove(other.attachedRigidbody.gameObject);
}
```

If your enemies have multiple colliders, then you'll need some additional care to ensure you add/remove them only once even if you get multiple trigger enter/exit messages.

If your trigger zone moves, be sure it has a Rigidbody to move with so that the trigger enter/exits are detected & handled correctly, and to avoid unnecessary re-computation of static triggers.

You can of course make this more efficient by putting your enemies on an "Enemy" layer, and putting the trigger on an "EnemyDetector" layer that only interacts with the "Enemy" layer. That way you only ever consider collisions between the trigger and enemies, not other stuff in your scene, so there are fewer false positives to process and you can skip the tag check entirely.

---

If you prefer to use this with an OverlapSphere query, then adding/removing incrementally is likely more work than it's worth, and you can just generate the collection from scratch.

```
public float radius;
public LayerMask enemyLayers;

Collider[] nearbyEnemyColliders = new Collider[MAX_NEARBY_ENEMIES];
int nearbyEnemyCount;

void Update() {
    // Using the NonAlloc version to avoid creating garbage every frame.
    nearbyEnemyCount = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(
                         transform.position,
                         radius,
                         out nearbyEnemyColliders,
                         enemyLayers
                       );

    for(int i = 0; i < nearbyEnemyCount; i++) {
        if(nearbyEnemyColliders[i].CompareTag("enemy"))
            continue;

        // False positive. 
        // Replace it with the last item in the collection and try again.
        nearbyEnemyCount--;
        nearbyEnemyColliders[i] = nearbyEnemyColliders[nearbyEnemyCount];
        i--;
    }

    // Now the first nearbyEnemyCount entries of the array
    // are all valid hits with the right tag.
}
```

Again, filtering your `enemyLayers` here can save you the false positives and let you consume the results directly, rather than doing an extra array walk to prune based on tag matches.

This array processing is also amenable to phrasing as a [LINQ query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), but I'll leave that for another answer if someone wants to show that style. :)

Comment: Thank you so much DMG for all this. The first  script did the job very well and I added int to count all objects in the list use "enemiesInRange.Count". But the second script it doesn't work. I not giving error but not updating the list !!

Comment: There's no list in the second script. Did you remember to set the layer mask you're passing to the physics query correctly?